# Game still not visible to newer android then 2.2

Tags: android

My manifest file is updated now and it looks like this.But its still not visible or not compatible on google play for newer android then 2.2.But i have tested it on 4.0 and its work.
Here is my manifest.Please help

android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1" >

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false"/>
<supports-screens 
     android:resizeable="true"
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:required="false"` from the `uses-permission` tag.
You're not supposed to place this inside a permission tag, but in a uses-feature tag...
Anyway, WAKE_LOCK will not need any required declaration:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: without that permission game crash

Comment: I didn't say to remove the permission... I said to remove the android:required you added so the line would look like my edited response

Comment: Ok.i will try.if you have newer android you can try to go to this link and say me what say to you if you have newer android then 2.2     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.charliethebravegame&feature=search_result

Comment: I see it as available to download with my 2.3.5 HTC Sensation XL